# Pig is storing the data in Temporary Directory instead of actual directory

Tags: apache-pig

Below `pig` command ( `local mode`) is saving the file in `temporary directory` where in i was expecting the same to be stored in actual directory. Any thoughts?

```
STORE c INTO '/user/hue/pigbasic1' USING PigStorage('*');

hadoop fs -cat /user/hue/pigbasic1/_temporary/0/task_local1045577955_0002_r_000000/part-r-00000;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Plz share the console logs after execution of STORE command.

Comment: _temporary files are created when the job is still in execution.